Is $H^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ dense in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$?
Let $H^{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ be the $k$-th Sobolev space. How can I prove that $H^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is dense in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$?
I was trying to use the fact that the space of smooth compactly supported functions $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is dense in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \subset H^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\subset H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \subset L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, but this was not very helpful as the density is with respect to the $L^{2}$ norm.
In addition, is it true that $H^{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is dense in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for every $k \ge 2$?

$C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as well

@HyperbolicPDEfriend thanks!! In fact I was missing this fact. So both the claims in my question are true for this density argument am I right?

Yes they are indeed true
